# Anchor to element within hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, hidden

I'm trying to make a href link to an anchor on another page (let's call it page 2 to make it easier), however on page 2, the anchor in question is contained within a div that is originally hidden when you first visit it (The div expands to reveal the content when header is clicked. So of course by default, the div has the property 'display:none').

Here's a small sample of the exact kind of thing I'm talking about.

```html
<html>

<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
p {color:#000;}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#f-hdr").click(function(){
        $("#hidden").toggle(1000);
    });
});
</script>

</head>




<body>

<a href="#anch">Link to anchor within hidden div</a>

<h2><a id="f-hdr" href="javascript:void(0)">Div Header</a></h2>

<div id="hidden" style="display:none">

<p id="anch">some text</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

EDIT - For instance, say if I was on 'page 1', I want to be able to open a link to the specific element on 'page 2' (in this case, #anch) But '#anch' is contained in a div (#hidden) which is hidden when the page is first opened. Originally, to access the content in '#hidden', the user must click the heading, which expands the div to reveal the content. I would like to be able to click the link to '#anch' (which takes me to 'page 2') and view the content in '#anch' without clicking the heading first.

From what I have seen, it may have something to do with the 'onhashchange' event. Although I'm not too sure (hence the post) :)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity, see edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of accomplishing this one using the name anchor attribute as suggested by W3schools.

W3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp

And another approach could be to use generic jquery method which behaves like name anchor.

**HTML:**

```
<a class="nameLink" href="#hidden" >Link to anchor within hidden div</a>

<h2><a id="f-hdr" href="javascript:void(0)">Div Header</a></h2>
<p class="dummy-height"></p>
<div id="hidden" >
  <p id="anch">some text</p>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#f-hdr").click(function(){
        $("#hidden").toggle(1000);
    });
    $(".nameLink").on('click', function(){
                $($(this).attr('href')).show(); 
    })
});
```

Note: Here **nameLink** is the class which can be assigned to any anchor link for using same functionlity.

**Finally the link:**

https://jsfiddle.net/Ashokkumargupta/bc1drx0s/

Hope this solves your problem.

Thanks,
Ashok

Comment: Warmer, but unfortunately not (Sorry! Starting to regret my choice of words in the question, haha) I have revised the fiddle into something a little more closer to what I'm working on - https://jsfiddle.net/bc1drx0s/5/  I want to be able to click the link and have it link to 'person i'm looking for' I understand that this is not possible while the containing div has the property 'display:none'. I need the link to jump to 'person i'm looking for' without manually expanding the div first (if that makes any sense) - Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have updated the code and link. Please check. Hope this helps! :) 

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/Ashokkumargupta/bc1drx0s/

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that you need to use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`.

I mean you need to change this:

```
<div id="hidden" style="display:none">
   <p id="anch">some text</p>
</div>
```

By this:

```
<div id="hidden" style="visibility: hidden">
   <p id="anch">some text</p>
</div>
```

For more information you can check this question [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

> **display:none** means that the tag in question **will not appear on the page at all** (although you can still interact with it through the dom).
>   There will be no space allocated for it between the other tags.
>
> **visibility:hidden** means that unlike display:none, the tag is not visible, **but space is allocated for it on the page**. The tag is
>   rendered, it just isn't seen on the page.

I'm posting the update with a long text added to it to see how it goes to the *hidden* element when you click on *"Link to anchor within hidden div"*:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#f-hdr").click(function(){
        $("#hidden").toggle(1000);
    });
});
```

```css
p {color:#000;}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#anch">Link to anchor within hidden div</a>

<h2><a id="f-hdr" href="javascript:void(0)">Div Header</a></h2>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
<p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
<p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
<p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
<p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
<p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>

<div id="hidden" style="visibility: hidden">
 <p id="anch">some text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR you have to make the element itself and all ancestor elements readily accessible on or right after page load. This can be extremely tricky if you can't predict what the page might look like (for example if content editors can arbitrarily nest things like tabs and accordions).

That said, if approached strategically such that all of your components have a predictable API, it becomes fairly straightforward to expand things outside-in before re-triggering an event that will ultimately take the end-user to the content they wish to see.  Be sure to take extra precautions like disabling animations animations and whatnot...and always do user testing.

Pseudo-JS assuming web components are used with a common API:

```
(() => {
  function autoActivateElementPath(element) {
    const interactive_path = [];
    do {
      if (element instanceof InteractiveElement) {
        interactive_path.unshift(element);
      }
      element = element.parentElement;
    }
    while (element);

    // From outside-in make each element accessible.
    interactive_path.forEach(element => {
      element.activate();
    });
  }

  // Auto-activate on page load in-case a user is visiting with a fragment in the URL.
  if (location.hash) {
    const target = document.querySelector(location.hash);
    if (target) {
      autoActivateElementPath(target);
    }
  }
})();
```

Full write-up: https://www.lukeleber.com/blog/2022-06-01-just-simply-smooth-scrolling-part-two

I've used this with up to 4 levels of interactive elements obscuring jump link destinations.  Whether the UI should contain that much deeply nested information is unfortunately a question for UX and content strategists, not the poor saps that have to support it technically .